# I can't log in to Minecraft please help

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So my friends told me I should buy Minecraft: Pocket Edition so that I can play it whenever I want. So I bought the app and the first thing I do is go to settings and press login but unfortunately it said pause, and mention further notice it been a month and I still can't log in. So this is I what I want to know: Why is it doing this? Has this ever happened to anyone else? What can I do to login?

P.S. This is what it looks like: [image] and this is when I press login: [image]

Comment: -1 because of title

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it really is paused by Mojang temporarily, see [this news post](https://mojang.com/2014/02/a-quick-update-from-the-pocket-edition-team/). You will just have to wait until they resume it.

Answer (score 0):

You must be invited to realms alpha. It is currently in Beta and when it comes out it will be a optional paid service.